Why is pynufft throwing this error?
I am trying to do a simple NU FFT of a signal. I provide time and amplitude data in a CSV file.
This is my code:
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pynufft import NUFFT

# Load time-amplitude data from CSV file
file_path = "test.txt"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Check if data has the correct columns
if "Time" not in data.columns or "Amplitude" not in data.columns:
    raise ValueError("CSV file must contain 'Time' and 'Amplitude' columns")

# Extract time and amplitude values
time = data["Time"].values
amplitude = data["Amplitude"].values

# Normalize time values for NUFFT, ensuring they range within -π to π
time_min, time_max = np.min(time), np.max(time)
normalized_time = (time - time_min) * 2 * np.pi / (time_max - time_min) - np.pi

# Define frequency grid for NUFFT
num_points = len(time)
freq_grid = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num_points, endpoint=False)

# Initialize NUFFT
nufft = NUFFT()
nufft.plan(normalized_time, (num_points,), (num_points,), Jd=(6,))
    
# Perform NUFFT
amplitude_nufft = nufft.forward(amplitude)

# Get amplitude spectrum and frequency in Hz
amplitude_spectrum = np.abs(amplitude_nufft)
frequency = np.fft.fftshift(
    np.fft.fftfreq(num_points, d=(time_max - time_min) / (num_points * 2 * np.pi))
)

I have 1D data, so I used nufft.plan(normalized_time, (num_points,), (num_points,), Jd=(6,)) as suggested in https://pynufft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutor/example.html but I get the following error:
+*Out[7]:*+
----

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

    Cell In[7], line 3
          1 # Initialize NUFFT
          2 nufft = NUFFT()
    ----> 3 nufft.plan(normalized_time, (num_points,), (num_points,), Jd=(6,))


    File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynufft/nufft/__init__.py:596, in NUFFT.plan(self, *args, **kwargs)
        553 """
        554 Plan the NUFFT object with the geometry provided.
        555 
       (...)
        591 
        592 """        
        593 func = {'cpu': self._plan_cpu,
        594             'hsa': self._plan_device,
        595             'hsa_legacy': self._plan_legacy}
    --> 596 return func.get(self.processor)(*args, **kwargs)


    File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynufft/nufft/_nufft_class_methods_cpu.py:78, in _plan_cpu(self, om, Nd, Kd, Jd, ft_axes)
         75     ft_axes = range(0, self.ndims)
         76 self.ft_axes = ft_axes  # default: all axes (range(0, self.ndims)
    ---> 78 self.st = helper.plan(om, Nd, Kd, Jd, ft_axes=ft_axes,
         79                       format='CSR')
         81 self.Nd = self.st['Nd']  # backup
         82 self.Kd = self.st['Kd']


    File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pynufft/src/_helper/helper.py:757, in plan(om, Nd, Kd, Jd, ft_axes, format, radix)
        733        ###############################################################
        734         # formula 29 , 26 of Fessler's paper
        735         ###############################################################
        736 
        737         # pseudo-inverse of CSSC using large N approx [J? J?]
        738         if ft_flag[dimid] is True:
        739 
        740 #         ###############################################################
       (...)
        755             #### phase shift
        756 #             ud += [QR2(om[:,dimid], N, J, K, snd[dimid], ft_flag[dimid]),]
    --> 757             ud += [min_max(N, J, K, alpha, beta, om[:, dimid], ft_flag[dimid]),]
        759         else:
        760             ud += [numpy.ones((1, M), dtype = dtype).T, ]


    IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Needless to say, if I skip Jd I get a different error about Jd being a required parameter.
I have been looking for examples and explanations online but it seems to me that my code is fine. Where is the mistake?
I am using Jupyterlabs to edit and run python code and I use the default kernel "ipykernel".

The array which was being passed to nufft.plan was a 1D horizontal array.
It needed to be transposed into a vertical array.
# Normalize time values for NUFFT, ensuring they range within -π to π
time_min, time_max = np.min(time), np.max(time)
normalized_time = (time - time_min) * 2 * np.pi / (time_max - time_min) - np.pi
print (normalized_time.shape)

(37,)
normalized_time = np.expand_dims(normalized_time, axis=0)
print (normalized_time.shape)

(1, 37)
normalized_time = np.transpose(normalized_time)
print (normalized_time.shape)

(37, 1)
